Let $f: A \rightarrow B$ be a function, and X be a subset of A. Prove that $f(f^{-1}(f(X)))= f(X).$
The Problem:

Let $f: A \rightarrow B$ be a function, and $X$ be a subset of $A$. Prove that $f(f^{-1}(f(X))) = f(X)$.

My professor took off all the points because I didn't use "equality of sets through double inclusion." It's not like I didn't consider it, I just thought it was not needed. What I did was I let an element $x$ belonging to $X$ (the subset of $A$) and showed that $f(x) = f(f^{-1}(f(x)))$ for all $x$, thus proving that $f(f^{-1}(f(X))) = f(X)$ where big $X$ is the subset of $A$.
How should I argue my point if I am not wrong?

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

In this context I guess the notation $f^{-1}(Y)$ for some subset $Y$ of $B$ means the inverse image/pre-image of $Y$ under $f$. So what you showed $f(x) = f(f^{-1}(f(x)))$ for all $x \in A$ is not correct at all since the inverse of $f$, aka $f^{-1}$ may not exists. This is a bit confusing about the notation of inverse image and inverse function.

I think inverses are assumed to be left or right so that they exist here so that wouldn't matter. I personally think the solutions is correct and the professor just wants me to use double inclusion(in which case I can argue for my points, she took off 20%! I was going to get perfect). What do you think?

@HaoyiWang You never mentioned in the exercise that $f$ is invertible. Probably because that wasn't given. As it was already mentioned, $f^{-1}$ here means inverse image. So your solution is completely wrong.

I seriously doubt you were supposed to assume that $f$ is bijective for this type of problem. @HaoyiWang

@Mark I posted a solution below that uses the inverse. I don't think it is the inverse that was the problem. What do you think?

@HaoyiWang Again, there is a difference between inverse image and inverse function. Inverse image always exists, and you indeed had to use it for this problem. The inverse function (which looks like you assumed to exist in your original solution) doesn't always exist.

Only having "$f$ is a function", really matters here, you have to interpret $f^{-1}$ as the preimage. Don't let the point deduction discourage yourself, rather try to understand the preimage, since it seems like you are bit confused there. If you write down $f \circ f^{-1} \circ f(x)$ for some $x \in X$, you thereby imply that the inverse function $f^{-1}: B \longrightarrow A$ exist. In your posted answer you dont use the inverse function, but rather the pre-image, which is a set. So the problem is your notation, which implies the existence of the inverse function.

@Mark I see, that is unfortunate. Thank you for the clarification

@tychonovs-scholar I understand now, I am glad that the mistake was pointed out. Thank you for the clarification.

Here's a solution I found, and it has used the inverse, I don't think you need to assume bijectivity to use the inverse notation:
Recall, $f(X) = \{ f(x) \mid x \in X \}$ and if $Y \subseteq B$, then $f^{-1}(Y) = \{ x \in A \mid f(x) \in Y \}$ by definition. The statement in the question is true. Here is how to prove it.
First, suppose $y \in f(f^{-1}(f(X)))$. Then $y = f(x)$ for some $x \in f^{-1}(f(X))$. By the definition of this set, $f(x) \in f(X)$, so $y \in f(X)$. This proves $f(f^{-1}(f(X))) \subseteq f(X)$.
Conversely, suppose $y \in f(X)$. Then $y = f(x)$ for some $x \in X$. Since $f(x) \in f(X)$, we get $x \in f^{-1}(f(X))$, so $y \in f(f^{-1}(f(X)))$, which proves the reverse inclusion, so the two sets are equal.
Therefore, we have shown that
$
f(f^{-1}(f(X))) = f(X).
$

Is that the proof you gave on the test? Because that sounds right. Notice that it is not the proof you referenced in your answer.

This solution has not used the inverse of $f$, it has used the inverse image (i.e. pre-image) of $f$

Apparently my problem was using function instead of image. I appreciate the help!
